# Why is the program showing no output?

Tags: python, mysql

I ran this query for fetching the details of "tom" which is NOT in the table. So, MySQL as usual returns 'empty set' if I run it in MySQL command client.

```
import mysql.connector as c
mydb = c.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='mysql')
pointer = mydb.cursor()
pointer.execute('use menagerie')
pointer.execute("select * from pet where name = 'tom'")
for x in pointer:
    print(x)
```

I ran this code using MySQL python connector but it didn't say 'empty set' like MySQL, just gave the following output:

```
C:\Users\dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe D:/Programmes/Mysql.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my question is how do I make the program return a user defined message when MySQL doesn't give any output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pointer.fetchall()` to get all the results. Then you can check if this is an empty list.

```
results = pointer.fetchall()
if len(results) == 0:
    print("empty result")
else:
    for x in results:
        print(x)
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-rowcount.html

Comment: Is that really known before the rows have been fetched?

Comment: yes. It gets it from the database, it knows.

Comment: What about the second paragraph on the page you link to? Doesn't that say the opposite?

Comment: I think it's actually dependent on the DBMS. MySQL knows it in the server and `rowcount` queries the API, but SQLite doesn't.

Comment: That paragraph says *"For nonbuffered cursors, the row count cannot be known before the rows have been fetched"* and elsewhere the docs say nonbuffered is the default. And the OP doesn't make it buffered, do they?

Comment: Looping over the cursor before checking rowcount will ensure rowcount is "correct".  I found it remained at -1 for empty resultsets (using MariaDB).

Comment: If you're going to loop over the results you can just use `fetchall()` and then get the length of it.

Answer (score 0):

One without `fetchall`:

```
x = dummy = object()
for x in pointer:
    print(x)
if x is dummy:
    print('empty set')
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of for loop, you can use `print(pointer.fetchall())`. So it will return empty set `[]`, in case of no result. And try to use `try{}...catch{}` for handling error/warnings efficiently.

Comment: `[]` is not an empty set. Please review your answer.

Comment: @deponovo Why? Given the context (it represents the "result set"), calling it that seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @KellyBundy then "empty set" would suffice. Two things are being mixed here: a mathematical or mathematical-like representation of the container and `python` syntax. Since the answer is directly referring to the code output, then why not being disciplined and keep the correct `python` representation of the `set()`, if that's actually what is expected.

Comment: @deponovo Because `fetchall` doesn't return `set()`. It returns `[]` (or a non-empty list in case of a non-empty result set).